# Removing SVPW from mainboard having a SMSC-MEC1633L-AUE chip

Tags: bios, password-recovery

- notebook model:   Lenovo ThinkPad T440 20B7
- release date:     2013
- BIOS-chip:        W25Q128FVSQ
- SVPW-chip:        SMSC-MEC1633L-AUE

According to [this website](https://www.allservice.ro/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3044) "newer" Lenovo notebooks are storing their supervisor password on the SMSC-MEC1633L-AUE chip. Is there a documentation available, describing since which year or which models of Lenovo do store their supervisor password (SVPW) on the MEC1633L-AUE chip? Or can one assume that if you find this chip onto your mainboard the SVPW definitely is stored there?

If I understand correctly, since the SVPW is stored on MEC1633L, reprogramming the W25Q128FVSQ BIOS-chip wouldn’t remove the SVPW at all and one is still not able to perform further changes to the bios. But if that would be the case: Why are so many forum-threads and videos out there (with significant upvotes/likes) showing/claiming how to successfully reprogram some BIOS-chips using the [CH341A-Mini-Programmer](https://www.onetransistor.eu/2017/08/ch341a-mini-programmer-schematic.html).

Unfortunately they never show the whole motherboard in order to see if they also have the MEC1633L chip on board, and even if they would show the whole motherboard, the labeling is so extremely small that one would not be able to read it.

[image]

To sum up:

- Do all Mainboards - having a MEC1633L chip - store their SVPW onto there?
- If so, does that mean that one has to modify (replace/reprogram) both chips (i.e. the SMSC-MEC1633L-AUE and W25Q128FVSQ) in order to get rid of the SVPW?

Comment: First, please ask a single question, not two or more, in each post. Second, there aren't Lenovo employees looking through these questions and so the information we have to answer either of these questions depends entirely on the information published by Lenovo which you've already reviewed. If they've chosen not to publish the specific answers to these questions we won't be any more able to answer them than you have been in your so-far thorough study. Finally, why are you trying to clear a supervisor password. There are many invalid reasons to want this, and few valid.

Comment: Since I got the notebook for free, I decided to install Linux instead of windows onto it, unfortunately my colleague only knows the "regular" BIOS password and didn't even know that there exists and additional SVPW. So, I bought the CH341A-Mini-Programmer and realized after successfully programming the W25Q128FVSQ, that the old BIOS-PW still works and the SVPW still exists. Therefore, I was doing some research and found the above-mentioned article. However now I am not even able to boot up into windows anymore, but the notebook now always asks me for the second password as well.

Comment: If the laptop was previously owned by a company, and it was retired legitimately and sold legally, you may be able to go back to them and ask them to unlock it and remove the supervisor password.